# Fix incompatible-pointer-types warning

Tags: c, pointers

Bonjour, I keep getting this warning, and I've tried everything to fix the warning w/o any result. The program still works, but the warning is annoying and I'd love to know the "why".

It's a table, takes input from the user for a position in the table, and uses that position in the function encuentRuta.

This is (part of) the code:

```
char encuentRuta (int posv, int posh, char lab[TAMV][TAMH]);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int altura = atoi(argv[1]);
    int base = atoi(argv[2]);

    /* Define the table */
    char laberinto[TAMV][TAMH] = {LABERINTO};
```

---

```
    encuentRuta (altura, base, &laberinto);
```

And the error I keep getting is:

```
>     warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char (*)[8][12]'
>           to parameter of type 'char (*)[12]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>             encuentRuta (altura, base, &laberinto);
>                                        ^~~~~~~~~~
>     laberinto.c:16:44: note: passing argument to parameter 'lab' here
>     char encuentRuta (int posv, int posh, char lab[TAMV][TAMH]);
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Omit the `&` before `laberinto` in the call to `encuentRuta()`.

The message does its best to explain it to you.  If you take the address of a 2D array (`&laberinto`), you get a pointer to an array, which is written `SomeType (*)[size1][size2]`, or `char (*)[8][12]` in your example.  To pass an array, you simply name it:

```
encuentRuta(altura, base, laberinto);
```